# How to Bind RoundCornerProgressBar with ButterKnife

Tags: android, butterknife

Am using [RoundCornerProgressBar](https://github.com/akexorcist/RoundCornerProgressBar) a custom progress bar library in android, and i use [JakeWharton butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) to bind elements,

So i tried like

```
@BindView(R.id.volume_progress_bar) ProgressBar volumeBar;

volumeBar.setProgress(tagVolume); //to increase progress bar value
```

and the log says

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testproject/com.example.testproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View 'volume_progress_bar' with ID 2131296532 for field 'volumeBar' was of the wrong type. See cause for more info.
```

the error say

> View 'volume_progress_bar' with ID 2131296532 for field 'volumeBar' was of the wrong type.

so how do i use wright type for [RoundCornerProgressBar](https://github.com/akexorcist/RoundCornerProgressBar) or how do i increase progress bar value in `Java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me `IconRoundCornerProgressBar`

With butterKnife i used like below

```
@BindView(R.id.volume_progress_bar) IconRoundCornerProgressBarnn volumeBar;
```

And it worked.